# phpStorm or xDebug breaks connections - how to debug?

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I've configured xDebug and phpStorm for debugging. Everything works fine, breakpoints are hit, but if I try to evaluate some expressions using `evaluate expression` window the debugging session is broken. I can't figure out whether it's broken by xDebug or phpStorm. How can I debug that?
Here is the last entries from the xDebug log:

```
<- eval -i 27 -- JEdMT0JBTFNbJ0lERV9FVkFMX0NBQ0hFJ11bJzM1ODQ0MTQxLWRlMmMtNDRhYi05OTBkLWEyZDRkYzg3ZDM4OSddPSRkYXRh
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="27"><property type="array" children="1" numchildren="2" page="0" pagesize="100"><property name="expand" type="string" size="44" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[dGFncyx0aXRsZVRyYW5zbGF0aW9uLGRlc2NyaXB0aW9uVHJhbnNsYXRpb24=]]></property><property name="fields" type="string" size="26" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[aWQsdGl0bGUsZGlmZmljdWx0eSxzdGF0dXM=]]></property></property></response>

<- context_names -i 28 -d 0
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_names" transaction_id="28"><context name="Locals" id="0"></context><context name="Superglobals" id="1"></context><context name="User defined constants" id="2"></context></response>

<- context_get -i 29 -d 0 -c 0
```

Comment: hmm, I've had some wonkiness with phpStorm xdebug before... when you say session is broken do you mean you no longer see variables and it just shows 'connected' or 'waiting for incoming connection' or something like that?

Comment: Yes, I no longer see callstack, variables and flow controls are disabled. phpStorm continues to listen for incoming connections. Where can I find status like `connected` that you mentioned?

Comment: you would see 'connected' or 'waiting for connection' in the variables column. As an alternative to using 'evaluate expression', can you not just add the function name or variable to your watches or does that break things too?

Comment: @Maximus If you can create standalone sample project that would reproduce the issue then I may suggest to file a bug to PhpStorm's [Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI) -- they will be able to tell where the issue is.

Comment: @LazyOne, thanks for the suggestion, but then I need to make sure it's phpStorms problem, and not xDebug's. Also, I've tried to evaluate simple expressions now like `$t=3+5` or `new ClassName()` and it worked OK, the connection remained and I could continue debugging. It seems that some complex structures cause connection to break. But the problem also is that sometimes evaluating the same complex expression breaks connection and sometimes not.

Comment: @mfink, _you would see 'connected' or 'waiting for connection' in the variables column_ - nope, can't see. When not connected it states `Frame is not available`, and when connected it just shows a list of variables. Maybe I'm not looking at the right place?

Comment: @Maximus *"but then I need to make sure it's phpStorms problem, and not xDebug's"* How come? You submitting ticket to PhpStorm devs and the corresponding dev that known MUCH better (than you, for instance) how xdebug and PhpStorm's debugger work and can tell for sure where the issue happens -- inside PhpStorm's code or before IDE receives the response from xdebug (hence the xdebug issue). **P.S.** You may also try upgrading to the latest **stable** version (you have not provided your xdebug/php versions).

Comment: @LazyOne, I see, thanks! _If you can create standalone sample project_ - what tools are available to do that? For web we use plunker, jsfiddler etc, how can this be done for php with Yii2 framework? I'm using php 7.0.0 and xdebug 2.4.0 RC3

Comment: @Maximus By "standalone" I mean creating the project with all  dependencies (and/or instructions to how to get one that would reproduce the issue) and provide whole project folder to the devs (can be actual zip archive or link to public github; comments and attachments can be set with limited visibility so only JB devs can see them). P.S. Right now it quite likely will be xdebug issue (it's RC and you are using most recent and brand new PHP 7 version) therefore I would suggest to try reproducing it using PHP 5.6 and stable 2.3.x (if your code does not use v7 specific stuff).

Comment: @LazyOne, I see, thanks a lot for your suggestions, will do! Best!

Comment: @LazyOne, you were right. I setup php 5.6 with xdebug 2.3.3 and the problem is gone :). Thanks again!